# How to exclude AWS subnet ids based on name in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I retrieve the subnet ids from the dev account to attach NLB to them afterwards. There are two subnets per each AZ. Therefore, I get the "Error creating network Load Balancer: InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone". I need to filter on the subnet names to exclude certain characters ("-lb-") in the name and only use the ones without the "-lb-". I know Terraform can use for_each argument and toset() function but does it have something like **contains** or **where** clauses similar to LINQ?

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "dev_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.dev_account_vpc.id
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_lb" "dev_network_load_balancer" {
  name               = "my-nlb"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "network"

  subnets            = data.aws_subnet_ids.dev_subnets.ids
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `dev_subnets` provides a list of subnet ids from which some may contain `-lb-` substring, others may not. For example:

```
# Returns ["subnet-1", "subnet-lb-1", "subnet-2", "subnet-lb-2"]
data "aws_subnet_ids" "dev_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.dev_account_vpc.id
}
```

In order to filter this list we can do the following:

```
resource "aws_lb" "dev_network_load_balancer" {
  name               = "my-nlb"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "network"

  # ["subnet-1", "subnet-2"]
  subnets            = [for s in data.aws_subnet_ids.dev_subnets.ids : s if replace(s, "-lb-", "") == s]
  ...
}
```

There are no advanced filter functions in Terraform as of today. `replace(s, "-lb-", "")` will attempt to replace the `-lb-` with an empty string which is compared to the original string. If they are equal, it means the original string did not contain `-lb-` substring.

Update:

If you want to filter strings which do contain `-lb-` substring:

```
[for s in data.aws_subnet_ids.dev_subnets.ids : s if replace(s, "-lb-", "") != s]
```

Comment: It's a great example. However, my goal was to filter on subnet names which contain -lb- characters. I was hoping that data.aws_subnet_ids.dev_subnets can give me names beside the ids but it's not. Looks like I can only get names by adding `filter {name   = "tag:Name" values = ["your-subnet-name"] }` to it.

Comment: If you want to filter string which do contain `-lb-`: `[for s in data.aws_subnet_ids.dev_subnets.ids : s if replace(s, "-lb-", "") != s]`